# Update data of navigated screen

Tags: flutter, tree, state, provider

I Have screen A,B. I route from screen A to B using

```
_routeToSelectLocation() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
      '/search-location',
    );
  }
```

**and then i something change in screen B and return to A. While returning to Screen A
i want to update text present in A.**
For routing from B to A i m using

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
```

Now, for updating values I'm using providers

```
 MultiProvider(
            providers: [
              ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: SearchByLocationNotify())
            ],
```

My tree Structure is like
Home contains Screen A
Screen B is not the part of Home (if I'm routing I guess)

Answer (score 2):

you can await push function and pass something to pop();

```
_routeToSelectLocation() async {
    final valueFromScreenB = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
      '/search-location',
    );
  }
```

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(valueToReturn),
```

Comment: I have just figured out, now I'm using now  static String source = "Where are you?";
before that i was using  String source = "Where are you?"; so now I'm accessing the same instance.